# dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() is not working on iPad, but working on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library and its working on iPhone. But I don't know why this is not called in iPad. I tried to put break points, but it doesn't hit the break point either. I put this method in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"CustomCollectionViewCell";
     CustomCollectionViewCell* cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
     [cell.downloadButton setTag:indexPath.row];
     [cell.downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     catalogModel = [catalogArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
     cell.cellDescription.text = catalogModel.catalogName;
     SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
     NSString *urlStr = catalogModel.imageNameThumbnail;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if ([self.catalogCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath])
             {
                  catalogModel = [catalogArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
                  [manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:catalogModel.imageNameThumbnail] options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {}completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL)
                  {
                       cell.cellImageView.image = image;
                       NSLog(@"%@",catalogModel.catalogName);
                  }];
             };

        });
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation makes the code you posted all but impossible to understand. You say "I put this method in cellForItemAtIndexPath." What you posted is not a method, it's a code fragment. You should post your entire `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, and use conrol-I to re-indent the code before posting it.

Comment: Why are you using 2 nested calls to dispatch_async with the outer one going to a global background queue and the inner one going to the main queue? All that will do is delay the calling of that code. What are you actually trying to do with this code?

Comment: Also, do you know if the completion block for your `downloadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:` method is called on the main thread or a background thread? If it's called on a background thread that would be a problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in concurrent image loading implementation. When `-collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is calling, the device executes code on the main queue. Assuming that `-downloadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:` method performs image loading on the background thread and returns instantly we can call it without `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...` wrapping. Otherwise we cannot guarantee that the completion handler is executing on the main thread, so the code should look like this

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"CustomCollectionViewCell";

     CustomCollectionViewCell* cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     ...

     SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

     // methods with completion block usually return instantly
     [manager downloadImageWithURL:aURL options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
         // ensure ui is updating on main thread and for visible cell
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if ([collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems containsObject:indexPath]) {
                 cell.cellImageView.image = image;
             }
         });
     }];

     return cell;
}
```

And the different results on iPhone and iPad can be explained by the architectural differences in technical specifications of testing devices.

Comment: Good explanation. If that's not it, the OP is going to have to be clearer about what he means by "...this is not called in iPad."